# Angular $md-dialog controller from external file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-material

Im using md-dialog from Material Design and I came across a small issue which causes me a lot of trouble.

I'm using this dialog as a form for creating a new record in db and I need its controller to be loaded from external file. The reason is that I'm using the same dialog in many places of the app (in many other controllers) and I dont want to copy and paste it to each one of them.

I've tried to write it as a service, but the problem is, as I'm binding data from form to the controller I'm using $scope and that way i got "$scope is not defined". When I add $scope as dependencies in that service, I'got injection error.
Do you have any ideas how to load modal controller externally so it will work even with using of $scope?

```
$scope.showNewContactDialog = function($event) {
            var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
                $mdDialog.show({
                parent: parentEl,
                targetEvent: $event,
                templateUrl: 'app/Pages/directory/contacts/newContact.dialog.html',
                controller: NewCompanyContactDialogCtrl,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                hasBackdrop: true
            });  
        };

// New User dialog controller
        function NewCompanyContactDialogCtrl($scope, $mdDialog) {
            var self = this;
            $scope.modalIcon = "add";
            $scope.modalTitle = 'Nová položka';
            $scope.modalAdvanced = true;

            // Country Selector
            apiCalls.getData(countryUrl, function(response){
                $scope.countries = response;
            })

            // Add New Object
            $scope.newItem = function() {
                var url = baseUrl + 'new/';
                var data = JSON.stringify({
                    code: $scope.newItem.contactCode,
                    first_name: $scope.newItem.contactFirstName,
                    last_name: $scope.newItem.contactLastName,
                    street: $scope.newItem.contactStreet,
                    city: $scope.newItem.contactCity,
                    country: $scope.newItem.contactCountry,
                    postal: $scope.newItem.contactPostal,
                    pobox: $scope.newItem.contactPobox,
                    price_lvl: $scope.newItem.contactPriceLvl,
                    orgid: $cookies.get('orgid')
                });

                apiCalls.postData(url, data, function(response){
                    console.log(response);

                    // Toast
                    if(response.status == 201){
                        $mdToast.show(
                            $mdToast.simple()
                                .textContent('Záznam bol vytvorený.')
                                .position('bottom right')
                                .action('Skryť')
                                .highlightAction(true)
                                .highlightClass('md-warn')
                        );

                        $mdDialog.cancel();   
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: please show us your code. Also you can use `locals` to pass data resolves to the dialog controller

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0Acq3E2U

Comment: code should be included in the question itself. You can update question any time

Comment: it should be no problem by just including `ng-controller="YourController"` to the dialog template`

Comment: @JakubMana did you try any of the given answers, please try them and let us now. About my answer, its something i already use and i know it works.

Answer (score 6):

To use as service you can do something like:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('newCompModal', function($mdDialog){
        var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);

       function show($event){
            return  $mdDialog.show({
                parent: parentEl,
                targetEvent: $event,
                templateUrl: 'app/Pages/directory/contacts/newContact.dialog.html',
                controller: 'NewCompanyContactDialogCtrl',
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                hasBackdrop: true
            });

       }    
      return {
        show: show
      }    
});
```

Then in any controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('someController',function($scope,newCompModal){
        $scope.newCompanyModalShow = newCompModal.show;        
})
```

And pass event in from view

```
<button ng-click="newCompanyModalShow($event)">New Company</button>
```

If you need to pass data also from controller to modal you can add another argument and pass it to `locals` property of `$mdDialog` or share through another service property

Answer (score 2):

Example of a dialog with external controller:

```
$mdDialog.show({
    scope               : scope,
    preserveScope       : true,
    templateUrl         : 'template/search.html',
    targetEvent         : event,
    clickOutsideToClose : true,
    fullscreen          : true,
    controller          : 'DialogController'
});
```

And the controller search.js:

```
(function() {

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('DialogController', DialogController);

DialogController.$inject = ['$scope', '$mdDialog'];

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {

    $scope.closeOpenedDialog  = closeOpenedDialog;

    function closeOpenedDialog() {
       $mdDialog.hide();
    }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your mdDialog config doesn't recognize your controller name because it belongs to an external file, then instead of doing this:

```
controller          : 'DialogController'
```

You should load your controller as a directive in your dialog's view:

```
<md-dialog ng-controller="DialogController">
...
</md-dialog>
```